# A selected file disappears after switching radio buttons on Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to have a user to select either one of two radio buttons, and depending on the user's selection, it shows **input[type='file']** or **input[type='text']**. Then, the user can select a file or input text.

I was able to do it using Vuejs, but there is one issue.

When a user selects a file and switch radio buttons back and forth, the selected file disappears.

Here is my code:

```js
const vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    picked: '',
  },
  methods: {
    isTest1: function () {
      return (this.picked === 'test1');
    },
    isTest2: function () {
      return (this.picked === 'test2');
    },
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="app">
      <input type="radio" id="test1" name="test" value="test1" v-model="picked"><label for="test1">Test1</label>
      <input type="radio" id="test2" name="test" value="test2" v-model="picked"><label for="test2">Test2</label>

      <span>{{ picked }}</span>

      <div>
        <input type="file" v-if="isTest1()">
        <input type="text" v-if="isTest2()">
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried `v-model` for **input[type='file']**, but it does not support v-model for **input[type='file']**.

https://github.com/vuejs/Discussion/issues/24

I also tried `v-on:change` on **input[type='file']** and **input[type='radio']**, and I can catch the events when a user selects or updates files, but I am not sure how to interact with each other.

How can I hold the selected file while a user switches radio button?

Thank you.

Comment: Check this codepen: https://codepen.io/Atinux/pen/qOvawK/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked the same question on GitHub, and a gentleman (https://github.com/LinusBorg) answered my question.

The solution is replacing `v-if` with `v-show`.

Here is the reference to explain the difference between `v-if` and `v-show`.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if-vs-v-show

Also, here is the link to my question on GitHub:

https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/8520